# APP_DEBUG=true is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my `.env` file, my  `APP_DEBUG` is set to `true`.

However, when an error occurs I’m just seeing

```
“Whoops, looks like something went wrong”
```

before, it works very well, I can debugger and see error messages now I can not display error messages!

Any ideas?

Comment: php artisan key:generate

did you execute this command?

Comment: You may need to stop the server and do `php artisan serve` again to reread the .env file

Comment: I am on production server

Comment: @pradeep: Please review your last edit, it might went in too fast and after the op had edited in more details.

Comment: @nabil: Perhaps on a production server there is no such APP_DEBUG? Not so clever with Laravel but can imagine that this is a standard child safety setting. In production, better check the error logs.

Comment: @hakre before, it works very well, I can see debugger and see error messages now I can not display error messages!

Comment: Do you have the config cached?

Comment: @milad I have already run the key generation!

Comment: As it worked before: What did you change/do in the meantime until you realized it does not work any longer?

Comment: @Devon how? if I have executed config cached?

Comment: Have you tried the artisan command to clear it?: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @hakre I do not know what's going on!

Comment: It'd actually be config:clear not cache:clear.  cache:clear clears the app cache, not the config cache.

Comment: yes I did cache:clear and config:cache command

Comment: @nabil: Can you reproduce the problem on a development system?

Comment: @hakre on localhost I can debugger and see error message! 
I think the problem on the production server when I ran the commands cache:clear and config:cache

Comment: @nabil: That could be it. Sometimes it helps to re-install the software on the server. I just would re-ploy the last known good version.

Comment: @hakre which software that need to re-install !?

Comment: @nabil: The applicatoin you're developing, didn't you ask about a Laravel based application? How do you manage the application lifecycle? (install, run, update, stop, uninstall)

Comment: if the cause of the problem are command cache:clear and config:cache how can i fix the problem?

Comment: @Devon if config:clear is the cause of the problem what is the solution, how can I fix the problem?